# If condition with a string condition

Tags: bash

I explain my problem :

That command  ;

```
data validate myfile.xml
```

should give me an answer like this

```
myfile.xml is valid
```

Then, I want to create an `if condition` like that :

```
if [[ ??? ]] ; then
        echo "correct myfile.xml , start analysis :"
        analysis myfile.xml myoutputfile.xml
else
        echo "uncorrect myfile.xml"
fi
```

I would like to add into the square brackets something like that :

```
 if [[ data validate myfile.xml == myfile.xml is valid  ]] ; then ...$
```

But it does not work, any idea please?

I tried :

```
if [["$(data validate myfile.xml)" == "my file.xml is valid " ]] ; then
> echo "Well done"
> else
> echo "Wrong"
> fi
```

I got :

```
bash: [[myfile.xml is valid : command not found
Wrong
```

Comment: `if [[ "$(data validate myfile.xml)" == "myfile.xml is valid" ]]; then...`, but you'd better check the exit code of the command (`echo $?` just after you ran the command), you can be pretty sure it will be 0 when the file is valid and something else otherwise, which you can rely on to simplify the condition into `if data validate myfile.xml; then ...`

Comment: If `data` is written well, its exit status should be sufficient to determine if the file is valid or not, without relying on output. Then you can write `if data validate myfile.xml; then ...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this :

```
if xmllint --valid file.xml &>/dev/null; then
    echo 'valid xml'
else
    [...]
fi
```

Just using *boolean logic*

Replace [xmllint](/questions/tagged/xmllint) by `data` if this latter command is well designed to exit > 0 in case of error.

Ex:

```
xmllint --valid /etc/passwd &>/dev/null
echo $?
```

The exit code is `1`: error (failed: `else` case)

Answer (score 0):

```
analysis myfile.xml myoutputfile.xml

[[ -s myoutputfile.xml ]] && echo "My output file is valid." && exit 0
echo "Myfile.xml is invalid." && exit 1
```

A note about how this works.  Because the condition is listed first, it is tested first.  The second line has no else statement, but it doesn't need one because it is treated as the default option; it will execute automatically if the test fails.

Answer (score 0):

I execute my command :

```
data validate myfile.xml
```

Just after, I tried :

```
echo $?
```

If it returns me `0` , it's ok , if it returns me `1` , it's wrong.

So :

```
data validate myfile.xml



   if [ "$?" -eq "0" ]
   then ....
```

Comment: No need to test `$?` ;)